# Save Range of Cells from InputBox into List

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select a range of cells in Excel and save the data into List, so I can use the List for other purposes. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub btInsert_Click()

Dim r As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set r = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter a range", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
r.Copy Destination:=(?)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

I've tried to declare a List variable and use it as destination, but it said "Error: User-defined type not defined". What should I write on **`r.Copy Destination:=(?)`**"????

Comment: I removed the tag information from the title because it is not necessary. The tag system here works perfectly well, and does not need any help. Please do  NOT edit them back into the title.

Comment: `r.Copy Destination:=Sheets("MySheet").Range("A1")` it should be a range object. [Range.Copy method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Answer (score 0):

`Copy` method is used to copy the range (source) to a new range (detination) or clipboard. Parameter `Destination` should be a range object.

> [Range.Copy method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```
r.Copy Destination:=Sheets("MySheet").Range("A1")
```

I guess `List` in OP title means array.

```
    Dim r As Range, arr
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter a range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    arr = r.Value
    If r.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ' value of selected single cell
        Debug.Print arr
    Else
        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        ' retrieve items from array
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
                Debug.Print arr(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i
    End If
```